# I'm going to replace my manual transmission. What else should I replace at the same time?

Tags: honda, clutch, manual-transmission

**Vehicle**
2006 Civic Si
115k miles
6-speed manual transmission (original, including clutch)

**Question**
It's getting harder to shift between gears.  When upshifting, I need to wait a while for revs to match perfectly in order for the shifter to fall into place, and when I'm at the track it can be tough to rev-match well enough to shift quickly.  I assume the synchros are worn.

Looks like I'll need to replace the transmission before too long.  What's the general recommendation for what should be replaced while I'm in there?  I expect that much will just depend on visual inspection, and I'm wondering about what to look for as well.  Specifically, what about:

- Clutch
- Flywheel
- Other clutch parts (slave cylinder, release bearing, release fork, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the mileage and your description I would replace the clutch no matter what if you swap out the transmission. But, before replacing the transmission, verify the clutch pushes the release fork enough, and/or try flushing the clutch master cylinder and lines.

Because a clutch that won't release fully gives the same symptoms as worn synchros.

If you do replace the transmission:

- Resurface or replace the flywheel, clutch, throw-out bearing.
- Like cano said, replace the rear main.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well change the trans fluid and possibly the rear main seal while your there.  But you pretty much have  everything.

Comment: drive shafts and cv joints too